# Suggestion to make the "Ask a Question" page quite a bit more useful

Tags: feature-request

I generally only "hang out" in the R tag and it's been a *super painful couple of weeks* (it may have been longer for others since I've only been able to get SO answering time slices more recently) as new contributors post images instead of data or transcribe data into super weird formats and also provide no code or code in images.

I'm a data scientist so I can likely even quantify this to show it's worse than I previously, historically remember anecdotally.

Anyway, are there any plans or would there be any way to formally suggest that — as folks add tags to a question — there is a very "in your face" `div` that comes up with links to each tag info wiki page (e.g. R's is https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) with a bold ***"Please review the following tag wiki page(s) to ensure you are helping other SO contributors help you."*** or something to such effect?

Sure, that won't work for *everyone* (some folks are just going to try to speed-leech), but it may help reduce the amount of seriously poor questions that at least the R tag is receiving. I know y'all can't do something just for the R tag and — perhaps the `div` should only have the "top" tag info page show up — but anything is better than nothing at this point.

I just went to the "Ask a question" page for the first time in a *while* on SO (and, of course I'm in one here, now) and, frankly, the little yellow "how to ask" is nigh useless (IMO) for helping improve initial question quality.

Comment: *"...post images instead of data or transcribe data..."* - Pictures taken of the screen from a phone are my favorite. This is not unique to any particular tag, and there have been numerous attempts to address it. Poor questions are just going to happen. Vote to close, *hope* others do so as well and move along. It's not worth loosing sleep over since if it has not been fixed by now, it's not likely to happen anytime soon.

Comment: @NeilLunn, All well and good. But the current link (a small-print "asking help" in the bottom right-hand corner) is itself pretty unclear. I can imagine many people reading this, as I did initially, as "asking for help" (which is what they are doing anyway), not "help on asking".

Comment: @jpp Agreed. But is the question asking for *one specific change* in the page which would be within reason? Or does this being to wander into *expanded Tag Wiki* territory. Which I'm pretty sure has also been discussed around in a never ending circle, and I'm really not sold on people actually being bothered to read anyway. The "photo from phone" is as much a case in point as it is painfully humorous. If people don't understand what is bad about that, then pointing them to detailed guidelines for a tag does not strike me as making much of a difference to actual quality.

Comment: Perhaps, but right now there is virtually no real guidance on the new question page. SO seems to have spent alot of cycles placing the burden onto existing contributors with the little wave-y hand and other CSS decorations to "be nice" to n00bs but done virtually nothing to help ensure new contributors have some responsibility to create better first questions to begin with.

Comment: I agree with @jpp, "asking help" is a rather ambiguous phrase; it links directly to the "How to ask a good question" page, so maybe it should just be re-titled to that...

Comment: Punishing a new contributor w/non-contextual -1's when they didn't get any real guidance for how to do things right seems bad to me as does expecting existing contribs to "be super duper nice" & paste boilerplate "Welcome to SO!" followed by a further pasting "how to ask a good q" boilerplate seems like something technology should be able to help with. I know it's easier for SO devs to sit back & high five for "mission accomplished" w/their non-icon hand for the "be nice" thing, but I have to believe they're going to start to lose existing contributors at some pt if the bad first q's keep up.

Comment: And, yes, I just snarked a bit at the SO devs, but it does _really feel_ like they did exactly what I said. If they can add it bit of CSS decoration to try to help existing contribs "be friendly" they sure as heck could do something about that virtually unhelpful ask a question page.

Comment: Definitely not related only to the R tag.  I've seen images and poor question layout many times from new members.  Perhaps a "suggested template" including "Intro and Context, Current Attempt, Desired Output or Goal, TLDR Short Version".  I think 99% of questions fit under that template or something close to it, and would be helpful even to older members...  Including myself ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, even programmers are users too. And every obstacle put in the way of someone *asking their question right now* is something for them to remove with the least amount of effort. If it's a popup message box, they click OK. Of course, they don't *read it*, that would take up valuable time when they really just want to get their question asked. If it's extra text shown elsewhere (non-popup) they don't even have to read it, they can just ignore it. Have you got a way of fixing human nature?

Comment: Hey stranger, we finally bump into one another on SO. We haven't considered anything tag specific, but are going to be running a variety of experiments in the coming months all related to helping new users ask better questions.

Comment: @JoeFriend Hey! And, ! We'll keep bailing out the R tag until then. Thankfully there are tons of auto-clipboard shortcuts for macOS.

Comment: I'd consider rewording from "Please review" to "In order to help you, does the following snippet relate to your question" or something. My wording is bad, but I'd try to steer away from "please review" as that may just put people off

Comment: +1, people have been asking for this stuff for *years*; across almost every site on the network too. The current situation is like a busy department store having glass doors that look like they can be pushed, but actually need to be pulled, and instead of redesigning the door or putting up a sign, management rely on regular customers endlessly telling people who walk face-first into the door that "you need to pull it". Then they notice some regulars are rude to the 1,000th customer each day who walks face-first into the door - so they hire a doorman to tell these regulars to be nicer.

Comment: This would help [tag:C] questions too, since we now have a FAQ implemented in the tag wiki. Other major language tags implemented their FAQs in other ways though. So the root of the problem is that there's no working FAQ system, as I proposed that we need [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285953/170024).

Comment: @user568458 It's especially annoying when they start to lick on the windows. You try to politely tell them that licking the windows of public stores is not socially acceptable behavior. After which the doorman comes to scold you for being mean to the window-lickers, who are viewing the advertising in the windows during their brief encounter with the store, thereby creating an impression of the store's goods being desirable due to the high traffic of window-lickers outside. Even though they never enter the store or buy anything. And it means that we need to constantly clean the windows...

Comment: "I have to believe they're going to start to lose existing contributors at some pt if the bad first q's keep up" oh boy, you don't browse meta often, do you? The deluge of fecal matter in more popular tags has been pushing good contributors out for *literally years* at this point, and I'm almost happy that lower-traffic tags are finally starting to feel the same pain.

Comment: I'm all for giving tag wikis and excerpts more visibility, but I'm not sure this will help people ask better questions in any way (apart from tagging better, and maybe redirecting the occasional off-topic question). There just aren't that many tags that have "how to ask" sections in their info pages (which makes sense, because it's similar for most questions). As for helping you find an answer, in many / most cases the best you'll get is a very indirect link to a book or something that will answer your question (which very few, if any, users will consult before asking).